# How to remove console-tools completely?

Tags: server, package-management, console

After removing console-tools using

```
apt-get --purge remove console-tools
```

I am getting the following error during boot

```
init: Failed to spawn console-setup main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
```

So it looks like remove messed up to correctly remove console-tools package. How to get rid of this error message?

I'm using 10.04 Server edition.

Comment: Because I've installed it myself to check something, now I no more need it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's talking about `console-setup`, not `console-tools`. Is `console-setup` installed?

If it isn't, it probably left `/etc/init/console-setup.conf` behind.

If it is, maybe reinstall it? `apt-get install --reinstall console-tools`.

Comment: `dpkg` shows `console-setup     deinstall` which I guess means uninstalled. So is it safe to delete `/etc/init/console-setup.conf`?

Comment: `dpkg --purge console-setup`